# Is it possible to give a user read access without seeing the code in Zeppelin?

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I can give a user read access but I don't want that user to see the code or run. I'd like to share the notebook as a report for that user. Is that possible? I saw same question was asked [here](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/135942/is-there-a-way-where-we-can-share-the-zeppelin-not.html) a year ago, but I am not sure if there is any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

Zeppelin 0.8.0 has a bad behaviour on that.

Although a user has only read permission to the note, he can switch button "Show editor" and view code behind the error message "Insufficient privileges to write note."